# rsync --archive local/A/ remote/A/ changes ownership of /remote/A

Tags: rsync

When I run

```
rsync --archive local/A/ remote/A/
```

the ownership of the folder `remote/A` is changed to that of `local/A`. I want this to happen only for files and subdirectories in `A`, not for `A` itself. How do I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`rsync --archive remote/A/* local/A`

That should exclude A itself (and also the . directory, under A, which also refers to A).

Comment: Running `rsync --archive ./local/A/* ./remote/A/` in `/home/pavel/temp` gives
`rsync: link_stat "/home/pavel/temp/local/A/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)` and 
`rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]`.

Comment: Mmm, you're right you can't use wildcards, I forgot about that.  You'd have to first put the files/folders globbed by * into a text file (e.g. "list.txt") and then pass that with --include-from=list.txt